# Ruby on Rails fb_graph failing with undefined method bytesize when executed from delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, httparty, fb-graph

I am using a combo of `omniauth` and `delayed_job` to integrate with Facebook. I have an `Authentication` model that looks a little bit like this:

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base

  def account
    @account ||= FbGraph::User.me(token)
  end

  def post_to!(opts = {})
    account.feed!(opts)
  end

end
```

So then from the console I can do something like this:

```
auth.post_to :message => 'Foo bar', :link => 'http://google.com'
```

... and everything works perfectly and an update is posted to my Facebook feed.

However, in the application I have created a custom delayed job that does exactly the above, only it fails every time with the following error stack:

```
undefined method `bytesize'' for nil:NilClass
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:830:in `block in escape''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:142:in `gsub''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:142:in `gsub''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:829:in `escape''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:822:in `block in escape_query''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:818:in `each''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:818:in `collect''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:818:in `escape_query''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:809:in `create_query_part_str''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:538:in `set_content''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:447:in `init_request''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient/http.rb:705:in `new_request''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient.rb:997:in `create_request''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient.rb:866:in `do_request''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient.rb:756:in `request''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/httpclient-2.2.4/lib/httpclient.rb:666:in `post''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/fb_graph-2.4.7/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:55:in `block in post''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/fb_graph-2.4.7/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:122:in `handle_response''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/fb_graph-2.4.7/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:54:in `post''
  /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@bb/gems/fb_graph-2.4.7/lib/fb_graph/connections/feed.rb:15:in `feed!''
  /Users/aaron/Sites/bb/app/models/authentication.rb:40:in `post_to!''
  /Users/aaron/Sites/bb/lib/share_activity_job.rb:39:in `block in perform''
  /Users/aaron/Sites/bb/lib/share_activity_job.rb:11:in `each''
  /Users/aaron/Sites/bb/lib/share_activity_job.rb:11:in `perform''
```

I have officially got to the point where I start throwing expensive computers out of the window. Can anyone offer any insight as to why it's failing, why it works when executed from the console but fails when executed from a custom delayed_job?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found an answer since when you posted ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. 
You have to use **to_str** in your code:

```
auth.post_to message: message.to_str, link: 'http://google.com'
```

Comment: it seems silly but this definitely solves the problem